# using stored procedure or web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, stored-procedures

I want to run insert statement to add data in sql table using C# .net form. I want to know that which way is better from following two?

1) directly using stored procedure with sql commands

2) via web service which then calls stored procedure

Comment: Better in terms of what ? Performance ? Flexibility ? Scaling ?

Comment: in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

directly using stored procedure with sql commands the reason is that the request goes directly to the sql server which is in precompiled form

Comment: so using SP will be faster